# Puppet is pointing to the older version ruby installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I'm installing ruby latest version (2.2.1) using RVM on CentOS. & set it as default version. following this link :-

http://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-1-9-3-or-multiple-ruby-verson-on-centos-6-3-using-rvm/

**Here my assumption is that i have latest ruby version & set as by default.**

Ruby 1.8 ships by default with CentOS.

Now when i'm running puppet server to install some default module it is still pointing Ruby 1.8. using following link : https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/aws#installing-the-aws-module

[image]

All i wanted to achieve is installing latest ruby or may be Ruby 1.9.3 version and configuring puppet with the same ruby version.

Comment: what is `rvm list` command gives you ?

Comment: Please see the output in following link:
http://postimg.org/image/4fwqhj2wj/

Comment: Can you please paste the result of `ls -ltr /usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: It looks `1.9.3` is at your default and current place. So it should be 1.9.3. But maybe something else is in issue. Keep trying.

Comment: @AmitThawait below is the output:-

[root@puppetmaster ~]# ls -ltr /usr/bin/ruby
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5184 Mar  2 09:05 /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: @jonsnow I have also spotted a weird thing

See the screen shot : - http://postimg.org/image/3od01uumd/ 
{Going to edit in my question}

Comment: I guess somewhere a ruby directive command is written pointing to bin dir of ruby 1.8

Comment: that's what i'm finding :(

Comment: Search using grep in all the files `grep -rn '<path-to-ruby-1.8-bin>' /`

Comment: To take proper inventory of your active Ruby, use `ruby --version` and `ruby -e 'puts $:'`. This issue might be Gems related, also check the output of `gem env`. - RVM can be quite a hassle. Your mileage might increase by using `rbenv` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using root and it will use the PATH for the root not the regular user under RVM. Unless of course you installed RVM with the root user which is not recommended.